# Display files by creation time

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to create a batch file that "Display files and directories whose creation time was a maximum of 10 minutes ago"

I have to run the batch file and enter the time in minutes by a parameter, and then see on the cmd screen the files and directories.

I read about the command "forfiles" But I can't find the way to do it for minutes.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You'll want to provide more information, including your batch file, in order to get any assistance.

Comment: Use a `for /F` command combined with `dir /T:C` to get the creation time of each file, convert it to minutes and compare it vs. the current time plus the parameter.

Comment: Are you sure that creation time should be used as this time changes whenever a file is copied from directory A to directory B although the file content has not changed? The last modification time of a file or directory is usually used and not when the directory or file was created in its current directory.